# Security when overriding current subject in weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager

Tags: java, authentication, security, weblogic

Because of my specific use case, I must find a way to override the current Subject in the WebLogic.

I have found a way by using SecurityManager.pushSubject(< Kernel Identity >, < My subject >). My custom subject is implemented the same as the normal subject when basic login in Weblogic, it contains a set of user and group principals.

My question is does it safe to override the WebLogic SecurityManager subject, does it have any security risk with this approach?